# What would you name the $fm(x) = \frac{f(x)}{x}$ pattern?

Tags: functions, special-functions

In my continued effort to optimize common patterns that I am seeing in engineering models, I’ve found a more general pattern of functions of the form:

$$
fm(x) = \frac{f(x)}{x}
$$

where “fm” is an arbitrary naming that I have chosen for this post.  My question for you all is:
**Is there an existing generalized naming for that pattern that would be better than “fm” (using an "m" suffix)?**
Or even: **Is there any specific case that has a traditional name that I can then adopt as a general naming pattern?**

For example, I often see this pattern:

$$
sinm(x) = \frac{sin(x)}{x}
$$

where not only can I optimize $\frac{sin(x)}{x}$ for efficiency, but also it is well-defined as equal to $1$ at $x = 0$.  So, does that have an existing name?

Similarly,

$$\begin{align}
tanm(x) & = \frac{tan(x)}{x} \\\\
sinhm(x) & = \frac{sinh(x)}{x}
\end{align}
$$

are both well-defined as 1 at x == 0 and can be optimized.

Similar patterns I see occasionally are:

$$ \begin{align}
expm(x) & = \frac{exp(x)}{x} = \frac{e^x}{x} \\\\
lnm(x) & = \frac{ln(x)}{x}
\end{align}
$$

I am also seeing these patterns quite often:

$$ \begin{align}
quadraticm(x, a, b, c) & = \frac{quadratic(x, a, b, c)}{x} = a x + b + \frac{c}{x} \\\\
cubicm(x, a, b, c, d) & = \frac{cubic(x, a, b, c, d)}{x} = a x^2 + b x + c + \frac{d}{x}
\end{align}
$$

Using an “m” or “m1” suffix for “minus one order” is the best naming I’ve come up with so far.  Another option is “d” for damped… though that would be linearly damped, as opposed to exponentially damped where I’d be dividing by $e^x$ (which may be another pattern of value).

**So, what general naming pattern would you mathematicians find natural for $\frac{f(x)}{x}$?**

I have to name them something in my software… just looking for some guidance from mathematicians on any existing or natural pattern that I should be following… as opposed to just picking something blindly that might be a poor choice.

Thanks for any recommendations!

Comment: For the first one, there's [sinc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function).

Comment: Thanks, @HansLundmark, and as often happens, once I know the name I find lots of interesting mathematical properties that might be useful to know when optimizing!

Comment: I see now there is similarly [tanc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanc_function), [sinhc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinhc_function), [coshc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coshc_function), and [tanhc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanhc_function) defined.  None of those indicate why the suffix of "c" was chosen for that pattern... does anyone know?

Comment: Wikipedia says "The term sinc /ˈsɪŋk/ was introduced by Philip M. Woodward in his 1952 article "Information theory and inverse probability in telecommunication", in which he said that the function "occurs so often in Fourier analysis and its applications that it does seem to merit some notation of its own". I checked the paper and there is no explanation for why the author chose this particular name.

Comment: It's sometimes called “the cardinal sine function”, and I thought the “c” came from there, but checked Woodward's paper too, and found no mention of it.

Comment: Ah, [Wolfram](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SineCardinalFunction.html) calls it the "sine cardinal function"... so, yeah, I'm guessing the "c" is for "cardinal".  But not sure how "dividing by $x$" corresponds to being "cardinal"... anybody know?

Comment: 'Cardinal' means 'of basic importance' according to a secondary definition in Webster's.  Since $\sin(x)/x$ shows up a lot in Fourier analysis, this seems to be a fine way to designate it.  It's not so-called because of 'division by x' but for its many appearances.  The other, tanc, etc. are following the precedent.  I think something like cosc is pushing the matter.  You want special numerical routines to deal with the limit $x \to 0$ of $\sin(x)/x$  or $\tan(x)/x.$

Comment: @skbmoore, I suppose that could be, but sinc is clearly less (not more) important than sin, so "sin cardinal" seems backwards in that sense.  An alternate explanation might be this:  Dividing something by its magnitude would, in a sense, yield its cardinality. So, for any $f(x)$, computing $\frac{f(x)}{x}$ gives you the number of $x$'s in $f(x)$... its cardinality, in a sense.  Does that sound plausible to you mathematicians?